# Unable to access IPv6 configured AWS instance

Tags: ipv6, amazon-web-services

I created AWS instance with IPv6 addressing scheme, based on the AWS instance it requires to add security groups, network ACLs and lastly configure web server to listen for IPv6.

I have added all the configuration as mentioned in https://www.blog.nodrama.io/ec2-route53-ipv6/

I also tested IPv6 works fine on my AWS instance and responds to ping

> ```
> ping6 -c1 -n www.iana.org
> PING www.iana.org(2620:0:2d0:200::8) 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 2620:0:2d0:200::8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=70.9 ms
> ```

I have Apache server running on it and added configuration Listen 80, that means it should listen for both IPv6 and IPv4.  However, I cannot access my site when I access it through browser using http://[my_ipv6]

I think I may have gateway missing but not sure if that is causing the issue. In addition, I can't isolate whether it is IPv6 from my local machine itself is not configured correctly and could be preventing from accessing web app through browser. Any hints on how I can access IPv6 app through browser http://[Ipv6_address]

Comment: What happens when you try to reach your instance in a web browser?

Comment: Use `tcptraceroute` with your IPv6 and port 80 it will show where the traffic stops. it is not clear from your description yet if you have an IP level problem or an HTTP problem.

Comment: When i reach from browser i get time out.  I see this site can't be reached with error_connection_timeout, taking too long to respond.
 It seems right now HTTP web server problem because I can ping other IPv6 addresses from my aws instance.